# FontAwesome Icons in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, icons, font-awesome

I'm trying to use icons from FontAwesome in an Angular project.
I started with the "Getting Started" guide you can find here: [FontAwesome Angular Getting Started](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular)

Everything works fine, i can see the faCoffee icon wherever i put it in my templates. But if I try to change it to another icon (ex. the "check" icon), nothing is shown.

I changed my icon declaration at component-level to make it look like this:

```
import { faCheck } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

Changed the html template to show my new icon:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faCheck"></fa-icon>
```

Then the icon field assignment in my component:

```
faCheck = faCheck;
```

Please note that i'm changing essentially only the name of the icon from the examples that i tested and are working at the Url i posted above. Even if I go to the definition of "faCheck" on my declaration, i see that it's defined so I expect it to be available.

Chrome console shows this error when page is loading:

> FontAwesome: Could not find icon. It looks like you've provided a null or undefined icon object to this component.

First attempt to use FontAwesome in my projects, useful general informations are welcome.

**UPDATE:** Got it working rebuilding my entire application. I was using VS Code, so when you save a file he tries to recreate the final bundle to let you navigate and check your development. I don't know what really happens with components in-memory state. I think the icon was not showing because of some misalignment of references.

Comment: Thanks for updating, this solved my problem as well. I was using HMR and had to clean my /dist and `ng build` again

Answer (score 12):

all you have to do is:

1 - add this to your index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

2 - use your icon as:

```
<i class="fas fa-check"></i>
```

You don't have to add anything in your `component.ts` nor in your `app.module.ts` nor install anything with yarn or npm.

**EDIT:**
To answer you question, here is a stackblitz with the faCheck used as mentioned in the tutorial, it's working for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ebr9t

check if you installed all the dependencies as said in the tutorial.

Comment: Ok, it's pretty clear to me how to use them as you stated. But my question is specific about the Angular environment and the official tutorial you can find here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular

Comment: you can also download the file and use a server copy

Comment: Don't want to because it's not necessary

Comment: this way works just fine in the angular environment, I used font awesome like this in my Angular Project and it's working as a charm

Comment: I know your way works, i used it several times in the past. But i saw this new approach based on angular components and wanted to try it

Comment: Got it working the way i linked here (using new NG component)...changing the icon to a casual "faBug" works. Maybe it's a problem with the specific icon i'm trying to use in my question

Comment: in dependency of stackblitz example, you used 'fortawesome/angular-fontawesome'

Comment: It worked fine for me in a [Stackblitz NextJS React App](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-react-bootstrap-in-react-app-6hz1uk).

Answer (score 8):

1- Install this `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

2- Add this to `angular.json` (`angular-cli.json`)

```
"styles": [
    "...",
    "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
]
```

3- Now you can use fonts with `<i>` tag

Answer (score 6):

I am using Fontawesome in this angular6 project, please take a look on the package.json, maybe it helps to solve your problem:
https://github.com/hamilton-lima/portfolio-web/blob/master/package.json

This is what I have installed

```
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
```

Make sure to import the necessary icons to the library you are using

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

library.add(fas, far, fab);
```

See the example here: https://github.com/hamilton-lima/portfolio-web/blob/master/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts

Comment: Updated with a details that can be the root cause

Comment: I dont understand as well :)

Comment: Remember, importing the entire subset of icons runs the risk of bloating your application. Please only import the specific icons you will be using. https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#using-the-icon-library

Comment: wouldn't tree shaking be able to remove unused icons?