# How to import font-awesome in STACKBLITZ JS project?

Tags: import, font-awesome, stackblitz

I'm working on a pure javascript project ( without any framework ) in STACKBLITZ. It has an option to install dependencies. But how to import it to my index.js file so that i can use in my HTML file.

I have referred the DOCUMENTATION of font awesome. But im having trouble in finding the path of those files for importing.

Comment: Hi [prabhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4894872/prabhu),
aren't you satified with my answer?
Have you checked the provided fiddle?
Let me know what's the problem to help you further

Comment: Hi @Meziane, I didn't had time to check this solution. Im sorry for not responding. I was held up with something else. I will check and repond as soon as possible. Thanks for the response anyways. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the following **dependencies** to your **package.json**:

```
"@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.21",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1"
```

Import **FontAwesomeModule** in your **app.module.ts**:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
```

and add it to the **imports** array:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, FontAwesomeModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

To use for example the *faThumbsUp*, *faThumbsDown* icons in the template of a component, you have to import them in the component's **.ts** file.

```
import { faThumbsUp, faThumbsDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
```

Add properties to the component and assign them these icons:

```
export class VoterComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;

  faThumbsUp = faThumbsUp
  faThumbsDown =  faThumbsDown

}
```

Use the properties (i.e icons) in the component's **template** or in its **.html** file like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
<button class="btn btn-primary">  
  <fa-icon [icon]="faThumbsUp"></fa-icon>
</button>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-comp-listens-for-child-events) is a working stackblitz. I hope this will help others.

Comment: Hi [prabhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4894872/prabhu),
I hope you will give my answer a try: please take a look at the provided stckbliz.

Comment: Hi @Meziane , Your solution actually solved my issue. Thanks a lot for providing me an answer.

Comment: Hi [Prabhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4894872/prabhu),
You are welcome.
Pleased to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get font-awesome is adding to your index.html the next line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

[Excerpt from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52006605/fontawesome-icons-in-angular-6)